# Unable to get my Nvidia RTX 3070 to work. Nvidia-smi returns no devices found

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, nvidia

I have a relatively new Asus laptop (~1 year old) with an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile card (in addition to onboard Intel graphics). I use Ubuntu 22.10 with kernel version 5.19.0-26-generic. I also dual-boot with windows 11.

I am unable to get my Nvidia card working properly. For instance, the `nvidia-smi` command returns no devices found:

```
$ sudo nvidia-smi
No devices were found
```

When attempting to play games or doing other GPU intensive tasks, the CPU usage goes to 100 % and the game is still very laggy, indicating that the GPU is not being used.

The GPU issues may (or may not) have started when I upgraded my Linux kernel a few weeks ago (I'm not sure, but I noticed the issue shortly after).

It may also be a conflict issue related to my dual-booting, since I have had other issues in the past with things like the Bluetooth not working in Linux after having used it in Windows etc. The device manager in Windows 11 also reports an issue with the Nvidia card and refuses to use it.

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled multiple different driver versions from system settings → driver manager → additional drivers.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled multiple different driver versions from terminal using `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-VERSION`, with version ranging from 370 to the latest 525.
- Tried to install nvidia drivers using downloaded .run file from nvidia.com.
- Disabled secure boot in bios.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers from within Windows 11 multiple times.

During boot I get these warnings which may or may not be related to my issue:

```
pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
Nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: unable to locate usable image
Nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: ctor failed: -22
asus 0003:0B05:19B6.0008: Asus input not registered
```

I have no idea how to proceed here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem if both Ubuntu and Windows have problems with the 3070.  Can you boot from a previous kernel (grub/advanced menu choice) and use the 3070?